# Query SQL in PowerApps PCF component

Tags: powerapps, pcf

I'm very new to PowerApps and PCF components.

I wanted to know weather it is possible build a PCF component which connects to MS SQL Server and pulls some data (Using msnodesqlv8 package) ? or PCF components are purely client side and used for only data rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCF is client side, you can query sql but you need to do it via API.
Access the API using any of the authentication method and then perfrom your operations as required.

Alternative, you can user [PowerApps (canvas App) and connect to sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase) or SharePoint and many more out of the box connectors provided by Power Apps.